# What does @public modifier mean in method signature?

Tags: java, syntax, apache-flink

We are working with Apache Flink streaming framework lately which is very nice. Nevertheless, in the documentation we stumbled across some Java thing that I haven't seen before, this class

```
public class MyMapper extends RichMapFunction<String, Integer> {
  private Counter counter;

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration config) {
    this.counter = getRuntimeContext()
      .getMetricGroup()
      .counter("myCounter");
  }

  @public Integer map(String value) throws Exception {
    this.counter.inc();
  }
}
```

What does the @public mean ont the map method and what's even more interesting why isn't there are return declared in the method although the return type is defined as Integer?

Or is this simply some issue in their documentation?

Here is the page as reference [Flink Docu](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html#counter)

Comment: Thanks for the bug report!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the documentation.

The `@` in `@public` is not correct and should be removed, i.e., this should be the Java keyword `public`. The `@Public` annotation mentioned in another answer is not supposed to be used in user code but just in Flink's public interfaces.

The documentation page is about how to use metrics, so the author probably focused on the call to update the metric and forgot the return value of the `map()` method.

It would be great if you could open a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK/summary) to report the faulty docs. Thanks!